# How Do You Override a Function in Powershell

Tags: winforms, powershell, overriding

All I can find online about doing this is to override a cmdlet, but I need to override a windows form event. Here is the C# equivalent of what I need:

```
protected override Point ScrollToControl(Control activeControl)
{
    return this.AutoScrollPosition;
}
```

They were saying that you just use the name of the function in the same scope and it will automatically override it, but that is not working for me.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[If you're referring to a method, Chris Dent's answer covers that nicely](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38753022/3905079)!

For native PowerShell cmdlets/functions I will copy [my answer from ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/q/642076/236470) here:

Yes, you can override `Get-ChildItem` or any other cmdlet in Powershell.

### Name Your Function The Same

If you make a function with the same name in the same scope, yours will be used.

Example:

```powershell
Function Get-ChildItem {
[CmdletBinding()]
param(
    # Simulate the parameters here
)
    # ... do stuff
}
```

### Using Aliases

Create your own function, and then create an alias to that function, with the same name as the cmdlet you want to override.

Example:

```powershell
Function My-GetChildItem {
[CmdletBinding()]
param(
    # Simulate the parameters here
)
    # ... do stuff
}

New-Alias -Name 'Get-ChildItem' -Value 'My-GetChildItem' -Scope Global
```

This way is nice because it's easier to test your function without stomping on the built-in function, and you can control when the cmdlet is overridden or not within your code.

To remove the alias:

```powershell
Remove-Item 'Alias:\Get-ChildItem' -Force
```

### Know the Command Precedence

[about_Command_Precedence](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848304.aspx) lists the order in which commands of different types are interpreted:

> If you do not specify a path, Windows PowerShell uses the following
>            precedence order when it runs commands:
>
> 1. Alias
> 2. Function
> 3. Cmdlet
> 4. Native Windows commands

Answer (score 2):

You need to override the method on a class not a function.

You may be able to override it with a script block (I've not done much with the undisclosed Forms-based class so this is a guess).

The Force parameter will let Add-Member replace a method, depending a bit on the protection / access modifiers in the class. This approach would work well for overriding ToString for instance.

```
$baseObject | Add-Member Point -MemberType ScriptMethod -Value { return $this.AutoScrollPosition } -Force
```

Comment: Hi Chris, the OP's method name is ScrollToControl returning a Point.  Are you using Point as the method name here? Thx